# Please add the secret GITHUB_TOKEN as an environment variable to your GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: spring, github, continuous-integration

As the title said GitHub action is throwing me this error while I have the GITHUB_TOKEN in my workflow.yml:

```
env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried assigning the secret as NODE_AUTH_TOKEN?

```
NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```